# Is there an available implementation of OpenCL supporting the fp16 extension?

Tags: opencl

I am looking for an implementation of the OpenCL language that supports the cl_khr_fp16 extension. To my knowledge, no publicly available implementation supports this at present.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're right, no implementation supports this at this time.
<s>But since cl_khr_fp16 ext is part of v1.1 (AFAIK) and v1.1 is coming very soon, you shouldn't have to wait too much</s>.

Roadmap from AMD:

[http://img251.imageshack.us/img251/1507/roadmapf.jpg http://img251.imageshack.us/img251/1507/roadmapf.jpg](http://img251.imageshack.us/img251/1507/roadmapf.jpg)

And NVIDIA already have pre-released v1.1 drivers:

http://developer.nvidia.com/object/opencl.html

Comment: From http://www.khronos.org/files/opencl-1-1-quick-reference-card.pdf , the half scalar and half vector types are still optional extensions in 1.1 for more than 'storage only' use.

Comment: Oic. I know that PTX supports `.fp16` but again 'storage only'. From NV doc: *The .f16 floating-point type is allowed only in conversions to and from .f32 and .f64 types. All floating-point instructions operate only on .f32 and .f64 types.)*. So it looks like current NVIDIA gen don't support fp16 ops. This also seems to be the case for current ATI gen (looking at CAL there is no mention of half-precision float at all). Maybe next-gen will support it?